# error: expected primary-expression before '}' token

Tags: qt, switch-statement

```
void ChangeStates(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<CELLS; i++)
    {
        switch (state[i])
        {
        case IMMUNE:
            timer[i]--;
            if(timer[i]==0)
                state[i] = HEALTHY;
            break;
        case INFECTED:
            timer[i]--;
            if(timer[i]==0)
            {
                state[i] = IMMUNE;
                timer[i] = IMM_TIME;
            }
            break;
        case EXPOSED:
            timer[i]--;
            if(timer[i]==0)
            {
                state[i] = INFECTED;
                timer[i] = INF_TIME;
            }
            break;
       default:


        } //Here is the error
    }
}
```

The program intend to do something about disease dynamics in plants, and use the switch function to change the state of cells.

I am using Qt Creator 5.5 as a beginner.
But I do not know how to fix this error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like its expecting some logic within the default branch. Just try removing the default branch for now and see if that makes any difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'default' has to be followed by a statement, 'break;' will work. Or remove the default as was suggested, this might mean better warnings also (unhandled enumeration value in switch, which is always good to catch).

You could also do 'qFatal' in the default to again catch an unhandled state[] value in the switch.